# Como recorrer consulta PDO en PHP

Tags: php, mysqli, pdo

Tengo una aplicación en la que necesito obtener los valores de una consulta realizada:

Probé de esta forma y si funciono (con mysqli):

```
//para conectarse a la Base de Datos    
$host = '127.0.0.1';
$user = 'root';
$pass = '';
$db   = 'incidencias';
$conexion = mysqli_connect( $host, $user, $pass, $db );
  if ($conexion == false) {
     echo 'Error al conectar a db';
     die();
  }

//para ejecutar una consulta
$sql = "consulta"
$query = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);    

//para recorrer una consulta
if ($query) { 
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
    $row['compoConsultado']; 
}
```

Ahora necesito hacer lo mismo pero utilizando el PDO de php. Por ej.:

```
//para conectarse a la Base de Datos
$dsn='mysql: host=172.0.0.1; dbname=incidencias';
$usuario='root';
$password='';
  try{
     $conexion=new PDO($dsn,$usuario,$password);
  }catch(PDOException $e){
     die('Error al conectarse a la base de datos: <br>'.$e->getMessage());
  }

//para realizar una consulta
try{
      $query=$conexion->prepare($sql);
      $query->execute();
    }catch(PDOException $e){
      die('Error en la consulta: <br>'.$e->getMessage());
    }
//para recorrer la consulta
//nose como es hace :(
```

Lo que no sé, es como acceder a los campos de la consulta, por ej que se consulte una tabla

Usuarios que tenga:
- id_usuario
- nombre
- telefono

En el primer ejemplo podia por ej. preguntar si el id de un usuario era igual a 1 con:

```
//dentro del while del ej con mysqli
if($row[id_usuario] == 1 ){
  //codigo..
}
```

peor no lo puedo hacer consultando por PDO, probé muchas formas sin éxitos.

Desde ya gracias al que pueda aportar.

Answer (score 6):

**Muy importante**: PDO requiere una serie de parámetros sin los cuales la conexión no sería segura, por ejemplo, si se usa sin el bloque `try ...  catch` y hay errores, podría estar revelando la contraseña en el archivo `error_log`, también si no se desactiva la emulación de consultas un usuario mal intencionado podría inyectar consultas maliciosas en la BD. **Lo más recomendable es tener una sola clase dedicada a la crear la conexión y dicha clase bien configurada**.

Aquí un ejemplo **básico** para usar PDO.

Esta es una función que devuelve la conexión o `null`. En todo caso lo mejor es tener una clase dedicada a la conexión.

### A. Creamos la conexión

```
function getPDO () {

try {
    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=prueba', $usuario, $pwd);
    return $pdo;
    }
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    print "¡Error!: <br/>";
    return null;
}
```

### B. Recuperar objeto PDO y enviar consulta

Almacenamos en `$pdo` el objeto devuelto llamando a la función anterior. Y preguntamos si es válida o es `null`

```
 $pdo=getPDO();

 if ($pdo) 
 {

      $sql = "SELECT id_usuario, nombre FROM personas;";
      $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
      $stmt->execute(); 

      //Aquí, cualquiera de los dos procedimientos explicados en b1 y b2. 

  } else {
      echo "Hubo un problema con la conexión";
  }
```

Los datos puedes leerlos de dos maneras:

**b1. Casi igual a MySQLi:**

```
 while ($arr = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo $arr['id_usuario'];
    echo $arr['nombre'];

 }
```

**b2. Mediante un bucle for:**

```
$arr = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
 foreach ($arr as $row) {
    echo $row['id_usuario'];
    echo $row['nombre'];

 }
```

**Nota 1:**

PDO tiene muchas más posibilidades de obtener el resultado de la consulta. Aquí se ha usado `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC`, pero [aquí hay muchas otras maneras](http://php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.fetch.php).

**Nota 2.**

Si quieres optar por una `Clase` dedicada a la conexión, puedes usar esta, o inspirarte en ese modelo: [PHP-PDO](https://github.com/padrecedano/PHP-PDO).

Comment: Gracias A. Cedano por responder, ya habia probado como la primera propuesta tuya y no tuve exito con estas soluciones, lo mismo lo solucione de otra forma no optima pero me funciona que es crear dos scripts php con las diferentes formas de conectar y llamar una u otra dependiendo lo que necesito

Comment: @CesarPaliza Debe ser **otra cosa** la que anda mal, pues yo lo uso de las dos formas que te indico y me funciona perfectamente. Si pones el código completo quizá se podría indicar dónde se encuentra el error. Tanto **A.** como **B.** son dos formas **óptimas** de usar PDO sin tener que pasar por soluciones complicadas, de hecho, PDO existe para ser usado así. Yo asumí que la conexión se hacía bien, pero viendo tu código, hay un `try`que sobra. En el mismo `try` que creas la conexión puedes enviar la consulta. Aunque lo mejor es tener una `Clase` dedicada a la conexión.